# Top result by date as columns per unique item

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of data collected over time in the following format:

```
Title | Date       | Value
-----------------------
test1 | 2015-09-18 | 99
test1 | 2015-09-02 | 97
test1 | 2015-08-31 | 101
test1 | 2015-08-03 | 11
test1 | 2015-07-20 | 100
test2 | 2015-09-05 | 102
test2 | 2015-09-04 | 101
test2 | 2015-08-22 | 91
test2 | 2015-07-19 | 76
test2 | 2015-07-12 | 66
```

I'd like to be able to output the **last result** for each month in columns for each distinct value so. The column headings (Sept,Aug,July) aren't important by the way. There will always be a 3 month timespan.

```
Title | Sept | Aug | July
----------------------------
test1 | 99   | 101 | 100
test2 | 102  | 91  | 76
```

Is this possible? I've thought about the use of CTE but I'm a little confused as to the next step.

Any help/advice is appreciated!

Comment: So there will always 3 ***exactly*** months worth of data in the table?

Comment: no sorry, the source table has data spanning back years. I want to pass in a min & max date which will always span 3 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with using a CTE to help prepare a result set for the actual SELECT.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Title, MAX([Date]) d, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY Title ORDER BY DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date]), 1) DESC) rn
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY Title, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date]), 1)
)
SELECT t.Title, MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rn = 1 THEN t.Value END) m1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rn = 2 THEN t.Value END) m2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rn = 3 THEN t.Value END) m3
FROM cte INNER JOIN t1 t ON
  t.Title = cte.Title AND t.[Date] = cte.d
GROUP BY t.Title
```

See working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2fbad/13)

*Note: This will only take the last 3 month of data per "Title", but will be un-aligned if for example the last month for test1 is Sept. and the last month for test2 is Aug.

Comment: this is my preferred solution. Thank you. I can adapt this to any specified three month range as I will have an effective `end date` to work with so can adjust the `CASE WHEN cte.rn = 2(,3,4,5,6)` part as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `CASE` to do conditional `MAX` for each desired  month.

```
select title,
       max(case when Month(Date) = 9 then value end),
       max(case when Month(Date) = 8 then value end),
       max(case when Month(Date) = 7 then value end)
from tablename
group by title
```

Comment: `case when  Month(Date)=9 then...` and so on

Comment: That's almost as useless as selecting the expected values directly. You need the last 3 months, not months 9, 8 & 7 of all years combined.

Comment: @Amit, of course. (Has the question have been edited after I answered?)

Comment: @jarlh - actually *the question* wasn't edited, just a minor formatting edit was done. But to be honest, it doesn't look like scgough even cares about the answers.

Comment: Ha ha, thanks for the suggestion anyway. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number` to get the last date in each month as the first row in each partition.

```
 select title, max(case when datepart(mm,datecol) = 9 then  value end) as sep,
              max(case when datepart(mm,datecol) = 8 then  value end) as aug,
              max(case when datepart(mm,datecol) = 7 then  value end) as jul
from (
      select *, 
      row_number() over(partition by title,datepart(mm,datecol) order by datecol desc) as rn
      from t1) t
where rn = 1
group by title;
```

[Fiddle with sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0dd28/3)

Comment: @Amit..it needed pivoting..modified my query.

Comment: And what do you expect to happen in a few weeks time, when October data comes in? Or if (as OP explicitly indicated) there's data coming in from earlier years?

Comment: the op said he will always have 3 month data.it can be modified accordingly

Comment: Read the question again. There will be a lot of data, the last 3 month are what should be outputted.  And besides, changing a query when new data comes in is a terrible idea.

Comment: what's your point finally? the op should be able to modify the query. it looks like you think you are the judge of all here.

Comment: Not a judge at all, but since I'm already involved in this question, I'm helping you (and the others) fix wrong answers. You don't have to pay any attention to my comments if you don't like to. Had I taken a judge role, I'd make sure I give verdict, and "punishment" :-) And the point is that (in my opinion) your query is lacking and won't work for the task described.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the values pivoted for the last three months:

```
select title,
       max(case when year(datecol) = year(getdate()) and month(datecol) = month(getdate()) - 2
                then value end) as months_2,
       max(case when year(datecol) = year(getdate()) and month(datecol) = month(getdate()) - 1
                then value end) as months_1,
       max(case when year(datecol) = year(getdate()) and month(datecol) = month(getdate())
                then value end) as months_0
from table t
group by title;
```

EDIT:

Oops, I didn't understand the original question.  Here is the revised code:

```
select title,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and year(datecol) = year(getdate()) and month(datecol) = month(getdate()) - 2
                then value end) as months_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and year(datecol) = year(getdate()) and month(datecol) = month(getdate()) - 1
                then value end) as months_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and year(datecol) = year(getdate()) and month(datecol) = month(getdate())
                then value end) as months_0
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by title, year(datecol), month(datecol)
                                order by datecol desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by title;
```

In this case, the `max()` isn't really doing anything, just pivoting the values.

Comment: This is good but it will get me the **max** value for a given month, not the **last** value gathered for each month.